# Is there a way to supply query parameters to a SQL Server Reporting Services Report at deployment time rather than at design time

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

SUMMARY:  I have created a SSRS Report.  I want to be able to supply parameters for the report at DEPLOYMENT time rather than just design time or runtime.

DETAILS:  I want to create ONE report and deploy it multiple times with the only difference being that I want to change one of the query parameters.  I do not want to prompt the user for the value.

Can this be done?

Seth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you link the additional reports to the parent report you can supply different parameters. This is easier than deploying multiples of the same exact report(.rdl).

[MSDN Linked Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256346%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I have a book I am using for reference on ssrs but since I didn't know what this featue was called I didn't know how to look it up.  There is a whole section on Linked Reports and now I am rolling.  

Seth

Comment: Yeah, linked reports are pretty cool. I actually just discovered them a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Change/modify the 'default' value for a given parameter within the Report Designer and deploy with the change.

You could also create/setup Linked Reports on the report server, assigning a different default value to each Linked Report.